# How to sync print and warn statements in Perl?

Tags: perl, buffer, output

I have a lot of logging to do in a program, a mix of print and warn messages. The problem is that the output is not in sync with the program flow, so sometimes a warning pops up before a printed message, even though the printed message comes first in the program flow. I guess this has to do with the fact that print goes to STDOUT and warn to STDERR, and both are buffered before they appear on the screen.

This little example demonstrates the effect:

```
for(my $i=0;$i<1000;$i++) {
    print "++++++++++++++++++++++++++ $i\n";
    warn "------------------------- $i\n";
}
```

You don't get alternating +++ and --- lines, but clusters of them intermixed.

I read here somewhere that there are some fancy things one can do with buffers in Perl, but I can't remember what it was. So my question is, how do I get alternating +++ and --- lines in the above code (retaining warn and print)?

EDIT: I looked up another question here and came up with this (thx to mpapec) for autoflush:

```
use IO::Handle;
STDOUT->autoflush();
STDERR->autoflush();
for(my $i=0;$i<1000;$i++) {
    STDOUT->printflush("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ $i\n");
    STDERR->printflush("------------------------------------------------------------ $i\n");
}
```

Now this one produces alternating two +++ and two --- lines. Still not the desired result. Also, it obviously doesn't use print and warn and therefore would force me to change a lot of code lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
use IO::Handle;

STDOUT->autoflush();
STDERR->autoflush();
```

and try to `warn` with `\n` newline at the end of the line.

Comment: Thx, but doesn't work for me. Even with added newline. Produces not the same, but very similar output as before. Still clusters of print and warn lines.

Comment: Did, and it again looks a bit different (bigger clusters), but still not as expected.

Comment: Strange. Will try it on another system. I tried it under Windows / Eclipse / Strawberry.

Comment: @jackthehipster, If adding what mpapec wrote to your program doesn't work, then I would have to assume the problem is outside of PErl.

Comment: Thx ikegami, even though I'm hard pressed to think of a place outside of Perl. But I'll try this out on different machines when I get to it.

Comment: @jackthehipster, I just noticed you said you're using Eclipse. It's got to read from two streams and merge them, and it accounts for what you are seeing. Auto-flushing plus the equivalent of the shell's `2>&1` will do the trick.